# C# RetVal complication

Tags: c#

I have this part in my c# code, The answer to the code is (INFINITE LOOP)

Can anyone please help me with the explanation?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Int32 X = 1;
    Int32 RetVal = X;

    while (X <= 5)
    {
        if (X == RetVal && X < 2)
            RetVal = 4;
        X = RetVal;

        X += 1;
    }
    MessageBox.Show(X.ToString());
```

Comment: Did you try to debug? It's not even necessary, from the code you can see that after the first loop `X` is `5` and `RetVal` is `4`.  And this will stay like this, because your `if` condition is now `false`. After the `if` `X` is set to `RetVal` (`4`) again and incremented => `5` again. So after each iteration `X` is `5` and `RetVal` is `4`.

Comment: This is one of the reason to start immediately to use a debugger

Comment: Maybe I should not have fixed your indentation. Maybe you thought that `X = RetVal` was part of the positive `if` branch?

Comment: @RenéVogt Okay, I totally overlooked the indentation after the if condition. 
Thanks for clearing my doubt. I am just a beginner to programming.
Thank you once again

Comment: @Alex the indentation is not the problem, indentation is not part of c# syntax. if `X=RetVal` should be part of the positive `if` branch you need to enclose the two statements (`RetVal = 4; X = RetVal;`) in `{...}`

Comment: @RenéVogt
Okay. I got it. Will keep that in mind.

Comment: Also take @Steve comment to heart.  Learn to use the debugger now.  It's pretty easy and you could have answered your own question and learned a lot as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X` is never greater than 5 due to `X = RetVal;` not being in the scope of the `if` block and `RetVal` never becoming greater than 4.